# How to get a list of property names in a class in certain a order

Tags: c#

I have a class similar to:

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
        public string Field4 { get; set; }
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
        public string BaseField1 { get; set; }
        public string BaseField2 { get; set; }
        public string BaseField3 { get; set; }
        public string BaseField4 { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a method to pull the names from the class.

```
private void MyMethod<T>(List<T> listData) where T : class
{
    String[] fieldNames = Array.ConvertAll<PropertyInfo, String>(typeof(T).GetProperties(), delegate(PropertyInfo fo) { return fo.Name; });

    // Do something with the fieldNames array....
}
```

So when I get my array it would be in the following order:

```
Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
BaseField1
BaseField2
BaseField3
BaseField4
```

I was wondering if it was possible to change the order so that the base class fields were first followed by the derived class fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's implement a simple method to get how deep is the class in the class hierarchy

```
null <- object <- ... <- MyBaseClass <- MyClass <- ...
```

Implementation

```
// 0     - null
// 1     - object
// ...
// n     - MyBaseClass
// n + 1 - MyClass
// ...
private static int TypeLevel(Type type) {
  if (null == type)
    return 0;

  return TypeLevel(type.BaseType) + 1;
}
```

And then with a help of *Linq* sort by this criterium, the only little trick is to use `DeclaringType` - where (in which class) the property has been declared:

```
// fieldNames are actually properties' names
string[] fieldNames = typeof(MyClass)
  .GetProperties()
  .OrderBy(p => TypeLevel(p.DeclaringType)) // <- base first, derived last
  .ThenBy(p => p.Name) // <- let's organize properties within each class
  .Select(p => p.Name) 
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fieldNames));
```

Outcome:

```
BaseField1
BaseField2
BaseField3
BaseField4
Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
```

Finally, your method can be something like this:

```
// we don't want any restictions like "where T : class"
private void MyMethod<T>(List<T> listData) {
  ...
  string[] fieldNames = typeof(T)
    .GetProperties()
    .OrderBy(p => TypeLevel(p.DeclaringType)) // <- base first, derived last
    .ThenBy(p => p.Name) // <- let's organize properties within each class
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToArray();

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some code like below to traverse the class hierarchy and then obtain the properties

```
static void GetProperties(Type type, List<string> returnValue) {
    var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    returnValue.AddRange(props.Select(p => p.Name).OrderBy(p => p));
}

private void MyMethod<T>(List<T> listData) where T : class {
    var type = typeof(T);
    List<string> properties = new List<string>();
    while (type != null) {
        GetProperties(type, properties);
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than having a method accept a `List` and mutate it, it should just return the items it's computing.  If the caller wants to add them to a list, or do whatever else they want with them, they can.

Answer (score -1):

Select all properties of base class and union with all properties of derived class. The Distinct() will remove all duplicates. If more complexity is needed you will have to try @Vikhram solution.

```
        var properties = typeof(MyBaseClass).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name)
            .Union(typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name)).Distinct();
```

Comment: How does this provide properties in a certain order, as requested?

Comment: The requested order was: base class properties first, then derived class. The code provides exact this order.

Comment: The method is generic; it's not hard coded to a specific type known at compile time with a base class *also* known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks. I've overseen that fact.